# Message-free flow-oriented logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, t-sql, decorator-pattern

Today, I've got a small `FlowLogger` for you to review. The idea is not to log pure messages, but focus on the flow of the app that might contain such items as:

- `state` - json-snapshot of variables etc
- `event` - something worth logging has occured
- `started` - the flow has started
- `altered` - the flow has been altered by some condition like an `if`
- `canceled` - the flow has been canceled before it run to completion
- `faulted` - the flow experienced an exception
- `completed` - the flow has succesfuly run to completion

---

## Implementation

The APIs are implemented by the `FlowLogger` that is build on top of the standard logging without exposing the original methods:

```py
import json
import logging
import functools
import pyodbc
from typing import Union, List
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime
from logging import Handler
```

```py
class FlowLogger:

    def __init__(self, name: str, handlers: List[logging.Handler]):
        self._logger = logging.Logger(name)
        for h in handlers:
            self._logger.addHandler(h)

    def state(self, **kwargs):
        self._logger.info(json.dumps(kwargs, sort_keys=True), (), **dict(extra={"flow": FlowLogger.state.__name__}))

    def event(self, name: str):
        self._logger.info(name, (), **dict(extra={"flow": FlowLogger.event().__name__}))

    def started(self, name: Union[str | None] = None, **kwargs):
        self._logger.info(name, **dict(extra=dict(**kwargs, **{"flow": FlowLogger.started.__name__})))

    def altered(self, reason: str):
        self._logger.info(reason, **dict(extra={"flow": FlowLogger.altered.__name__}))

    def canceled(self, reason: Union[str | None]):
        self._logger.warning(reason, **dict(extra={"flow": FlowLogger.canceled.__name__}))

    def faulted(self, **kwargs):
        self._logger.exception(None, extra=dict(**kwargs, **{"flow": FlowLogger.faulted.__name__}))

    def completed(self, **kwargs):
        self._logger.info(None, **dict(extra=dict(**kwargs, **{"flow": FlowLogger.completed.__name__})))
```

---

In order to not repeat myself when logging the flow of entire methods the `telemetry` decorator takes over:

```py
def telemetry(flow: FlowLogger):
    def decorate(decoratee):
        @functools.wraps(decoratee)
        def wrapper(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs):
            with FlowScope(flow, decoratee.__name__):
                return decoratee(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

It's supported by the `FlowScope` that handles the time measurement and exception handling:

```py
class FlowScope:
    def __init__(self, flow: FlowLogger, api: str):
        self.flow = flow
        self.api = api
        self.start = timer()
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        flow.started(api=self.api)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            flow.faulted(api=self.api, elapsed=timer() - self.start)
        else:
            flow.completed(api=self.api, elapsed=timer() - self.start)
```

---

The output is handled by the `SqlServerHandler`:

```sql
    create table log(
        [id] int identity(1,1) primary key,
        [timestamp] datetime2,
        [logger] nvarchar(50),
        [module] nvarchar(200),
        [api] nvarchar(200),
        [flow] nvarchar(50),
        [elapsed] float,
        [message] nvarchar(max),
        [line] int
    )
```

```py
class SqlServerHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, server: str, database: str, username: str, password: str):
        super().__init__(logging.INFO)
        connection = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}")
        self.db = connection.cursor()

    def emit(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            record.exc_text = logging.Formatter().formatException(record.exc_info)

        self.db.execute(
            "INSERT INTO log([timestamp], [logger], [module], [api], [flow], [elapsed], [message], [line]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created),
            record.name,
            record.module,
            record.api if hasattr(record, "api") else record.funcName,
            record.flow if hasattr(record, "flow") else None,
            record.elapsed if hasattr(record, "elapsed") else None,
            record.exc_text if record.exc_text else record.msg,
            record.lineno
        )
        self.db.commit()
```

---

## Example

This is my *dirty* code for how I'm testing it:

```py
def initialize_telemetry() -> FlowLogger:
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(style="{", fmt="{asctime} | {module}.{funcName} | {flow} | {message}", defaults={"flow": "<flow>", "message": "<message>"}))
    sql_server_handler = SqlServerHandler(server="localhost,1433", database="master", username="sa", password="***")

    flow = FlowLogger("test-logger", [stream_handler, sql_server_handler])

    try:
        return flow
    finally:
        flow.completed()


flow = initialize_telemetry()


@telemetry(flow)
def flow_decorator_test():
    raise ValueError
    pass


def flow_test():
    flow.started("Custom flow.")
    flow.state(foo="bar")

    if True:
        flow.altered("The value was true.")

    try:
        raise ValueError
    except:
        flow.faulted()

    flow.completed()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flow_test()
    flow_decorator_test()
```

---

What do you think? Would say I'm doing something terribly wrong here?

Comment: There is a new version, a follow-up of this question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279261/message-free-flow-oriented-logger).